# How to get functions from a .so file into my python program?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I'm a mechanical engineer trying to make it in the world of deep learning so my knowledge of programming is pretty basic. I have a pre-compiled file in .so format and my python file (nndistance.py) imports two function from this particular file as follows.

from metrics.StructuralLosses.StructuralLossesBackend import NNDistance, NNDistanceGrad

But I'm facing the following error

ImportError: ./StructuralLosses/St                                                                                                             ructuralLossesBackend.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6caff                                                                                                             e28TypeMeta21_typeMetaDataInstanceIdEEPKNS_6detail12TypeMetaDataEv

How do I go about fixing this?

I tried to fetch them by writing a script which goes

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'StructuralLossesBackend.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

I have saved this as StructuralLossesBackend.py

Comment: Sounds a bit like your shared library (.so) depends on another library it can't find at runtime (probably caffe2). Run `ldd ./StructuralLosses/StructuralLossesBackend.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and see what the runtime linker tells you - any libraries listed as "not found" are dependencies you either need to find, or need to add to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: We might need some details on how you built the so (and the code). What's undefined symbol: _ZN6caff? Is it in the so symbols?

Comment: I'm not sure. I had to download this .so file from google drive (as instructed by the git repo owner) so, sadly even I don't have a lot of details on this file

Comment: Clearly it is missing symbols from the `caffe` library. Were there other `.so` files next to this one?

Comment: @Botje No. It had just this file.

Comment: Then you're boned, unless you can carefully compile that caffe library with the same compiler version and options as the original author used.